# CloudKit allUserIdentitiesFromContacts() failing due to too many requests (http 429)

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm making a simple call to fetch all app users in contacts:

```
let userIdentities = try await CKContainer.default().allUserIdentitiesFromContacts()
```

which fails with the message:

> Request failed with http status code 429

HTTP 429 is the code for too many requests.

I get the same response in both development and production apps.

I've tried this in a test app that only makes this and no other calls, with the same result.

I have nearly 1,000 contacts on the phone where this fails. On another test device that only has 2 contacts, the request succeeds.

I'm assuming this is a bug, but just asking in case I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, did you get any further with this issue?

Comment: @pfandrade I didn't, in fact I raised a bug with Apple.